# Trying to prevent posting empty value in a textarea using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple application that submits that from a textarea on entering the enter command of the keyboard. I am trying to prevent the user from submit empty data to the form using javascript, here is my attempt but my challenge is that it is submitting to pressing enter keyboard

```
document.getElementById('new-input').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13 && $(this).val().length > 0) { // enter key press     && $(this).val().length > 0
        e.preventDefault();
        send();
    }
});
```

here is the send method

```
function send() {
        var message = document.getElementById('new-input').value.trim(),
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       // alert('first message>>>>> '+message);

        xhr.onload = function (response) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                document.getElementById('new-input').value = '';

            } else {
                alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
                location.href = '/';
            }
        };
        xhr.send(encodeURI('message=' + message));

    }
```

Please how can I prevent the user from submitting empty value. using either angularjs or javascript

Comment: Why tag this with angularjs, when angular is not a possible answer due to how the code is structured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to use [$.trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to check to white-space:

```
if ( code == 13 && $.trim($(this).val()) )
```

Will be returns true if not empty.